# I want a more dynamic approach to loading from an XML file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

**The Way it works currently**

Currently, I have several XML files that are exporting(correctly) from an external database. The XML file is read in the head of the HTML document, in the normal way;

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.open("GET", "../xml/TEAM.xml", false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
```

Then the HTML page they are displayed on is split into 4 columns using div tags. These 4 columns are next to each other and within them the data is displayed.

To display the data is use script tags within the div like so;

```
<script>
    var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("employee");

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        switch(x[i].getElementsByTagName("active")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue)
        {
            case "Yes":
                document.write("<table border='0'>");
                document.write("<tr><td id=pic><img src=../images/employees/");
                document.write(trimMyNode(x[i].getElementsByTagName("id")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue));
                document.write(".png width=100 height=100></td><td id=Yes>");
                document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                document.write("</td></tr>");
                document.write("</table>");
                break;
            case "No ":
                document.write("<table border='0'>");
                document.write("<tr><td id=pic><img src=../images/employees/");
                document.write(trimMyNode(x[i].getElementsByTagName("id")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue));
                document.write(".png width=100 height=100></td><td id=No>");
                document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                document.write("</td></tr>");
                document.write("</table>");
                break;
            default:
                document.write("<tr><td id=pic></td><td></td></tr>");
        }
}
</script>
```

As you can see this loads the employee's into individual tables and places them below each other, in groups of 4. This is the same across the 4 div tags so that each page displays 16 employees.

**What i want**

The way i want it to work is so that there is an XML file with say... 40 employees in it, 20 from 1 team, 20 from another team.

I want the code to read the XML file and select the ones just from Team 1. Then i want it to work out how many there are and to display them across 1 or 2 pages.

I've tried a few different tactics to do so but i am fairly new to javascript and have exhausted my knowledge of it.

Any help would be appreciated :)